# Ruby On Rails: Convert PostgreSQL JSON to usual JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

I have a JSON field in my PostgreSQL database. If I do `@profile.json`, then I will get something like:

```
{ {"name"=>"jhon", "degree"=>"12312"}, "1480103144467"=>{"name"=>"", "degree"=>""}}`
```

It has all the `=>` and other symbols, which I can not parse. How can I convert to normal format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've declared your column of type `json` that's a signal to Rails to automatically serialize and decode your column on-demand, transparently. What you're seeing here is a traditional Ruby Hash structure, which is to be expected.

Inside the database itself it's stored as JSON.

If you need to re-emit this as JSON for whatever reason, like for an API, try this:

```
@profile.json.to_json
```

Calling your column something other than `json` is probably advisable, too.

Comment: Wasn't 100% sure about PostgreSQL, but was looking at this like... this looks like Ruby rockets. Good stuff!

Comment: Yeah, Ruby's support for Postgres JSON columns is fantastic but also confusingly transparent if you're not expecting it.

Comment: Oh, it actually serializes it straight away. Nice!

Comment: Yeah I've heard good things about Arrays too. Might have to get PostgreSQL running over the weekend :)

Comment: Postgres `ARRAY` and `HSTORE` columns are great as well. The `JSONB` column is where it's at, though, it does everything those do, and way more. Try using Postgres 9.5 or better to get the latest JSON features.